# How can to make Flowplayer support seeking in time bar?

Tags: javascript, php, flowplayer

Flowplayer v 6.0.5 has problem in flash engine and it not work ( seeking ) in time bar.

I am use Flowplayer 6.0.5 and video type is mp4  .

Please help to solve this problem to make (Flowplayer) seeking in time bar ; when flowplayer is using flash engine .

Answer (score -1):

Add the below code to your CSS

```
.fp-timeline 
{    cursor: default;
     pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```